# r data frame check next n number of variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows where x is a boolean column

```
id    |        p    |     q
------+-------------+----------
 1    |        1    |     n
 1    |        0    |     y     
 1    |        0    |     y
 2    |        0    |     n
 2    |        1    |     y
 2    |        0    |     n
 2    |        0    |     y 
 3    |        0    |     n
 3    |        1    |     y
 3    |        0    |     n
 3    |        0    |     n
```

I have a variable n. If the p is 1, I want to check if, in the next n number of rows (that belongs to the same id), column q's value is y. If it is, I want to create a new column r, where the value for that column is y, else n. If p is not 1, by default r will be empty. As follows (let's say it's 2 for example)

```
id    |        p    |     q    |     r
------+-------------+----------+----------
 1    |        1    |     n    |     y
 1    |        0    |     y    |     -
 1    |        0    |     y    |     -
 2    |        0    |     n    |     -
 2    |        1    |     y    |     y
 2    |        0    |     n    |     -
 2    |        0    |     y    |     -
 3    |        0    |     n    |     -
 3    |        1    |     y    |     n
 3    |        0    |     n    |     -
 3    |        0    |     n    |     -
```

Can lead function be used for this? (where I can dynamically set the number of rows to be checked)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would be good to show your attempts to create the new variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have variable `n`, I think `lead` would not be fit here. Instead you can try to subset `q` values for each `id` and check if all of them have value `"y"` for next `n` rows.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 2

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(r = case_when(p == 1 & 
             all(q[(which.max(p == 1) + 1) : (which.max(p == 1) + n)] == "y") ~ "y",
                       p == 1 ~ "n",
                       TRUE ~ "-"))


#      id     p q     r    
#   <int> <int> <fct> <chr>
# 1     1     1 n     y    
# 2     1     0 y     -    
# 3     1     0 y     -    
# 4     2     0 n     -    
# 5     2     1 y     n    
# 6     2     0 n     -    
# 7     2     0 y     -    
# 8     3     0 n     -    
# 9     3     1 y     n    
#10     3     0 n     -    
#11     3     0 n     -
```

Answer (score 2):

I will be providing one of the possible solutions using {data.table}.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                 p = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 q = c("n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n"))

# Here DT2 is another data.table containing only cases where p is 0
# I will use this to see if there are any "y" in column "q"
DT2 <- DT[p == 0, ]
DT2 <- DT2[, .(r = paste0(q, collapse = "")), by = id]
DT2[, r := ifelse(grepl("y", r), "y", "n")]

# Then I will join the tables together
setkey(DT, id)
setkey(DT2, id)

# And remove the values of column "r" when column "p" has value of 0 
DT <- DT[DT2]
DT[p == 0, r := NA]
```